# Sending large string with POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

API I'm trying to use accepts images as base64 strings, max size for an image is 20mb.

Images I'm trying to upload are ~1mb but I'm still getting Error 413.

I'm not familiar with HTTP and have no idea how one would split the request.

I saw the usage of request toolbelt with MultipartEncoder for large images; but like i said im trying to send the image as a string.

```
import base64
import requests

with open("exampleimage.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf8')

data = {
  "content": "Updated card from API",
  "deck-id": deck_id,
  "pos": pos,
  "attachments": [
    {
      "file-name": "image.jpg",
      "content-type": "image/jpg",
      "data": encoded_string
    }
  ]
}

response = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(key, '')) 
#Only an API key is needed instead of the username:password
```

Thanks.

Comment: mp uploader is prob the way to go, agreed. that is, assuming the server supports it.

Comment: The server seems to have a max-file-size for uploads. Thus the HTTP status [413 Payload Too Large](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/status/413). Maye you can compress it. Without any API-docs (links) for the server-side I assume we can't help you here.

Comment: @hc_dev There is a max-file-size and it is 20mb; what im sending are just 1mb.  Docs: https://mochi.cards/docs/api/